# how to do vi style navigation in rail console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vi, irb, rails-console, bash

How can I do VI style navigation in rails console?

In my .bash_profile i do `set -o vi` and then in my terminals I enjoy vi style navigation.
I can do `dd` to delete a line, `cmd+$` to jump to end of line, etc etc.

I want to get the same thing in rails console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the editing-mode to vi. 
The easiest way to do that is simply creating the file .inputrc in your home folder and add the mode:

`$ echo "set editing-mode vi" >> ~/.inputrc`

And voilá!

Comment: I did this but it goes right back from command mode to entry mode after i click on any key in the command mode. How can I have it stay in the command mode, until I click "i" to get back in to the insert mode?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it, but hit the **'ESC'** key so you can browse the  command mode. So, you can use:
- ESC: command mode, cancels last command
- ESC,k: one line up
- ESC,j: one line down
- ESC,l: one char right
- ESC,h: one char left
- ESC,w: one word right
- ESC,b: one word left
- ESC,i: insert mode
- ESC,d: delete mode
- ESC,/: find mode
- etc.

Comment: yea but, i shouldn't have to hit ESC every time.. i should be able to do like `ESC b b b b` and that should take me back 4 words. Right now I have to do `ESC b ESC b ESC b ESC b`. Is this your experience as well or do I have something setup wrong?

Comment: That's not my experience, I only have to hit ESC once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue although using inputrc didn't work. The reason it didn't work though is because I was using zsh as my shell.  Zsh does NOT use inputrc for setting the input mode. Hence if you want to use vi editing mode in rails console and you're using zsh as your shell do the following:

Add the following to your ~/.zshrc

```
bindkey -v
```

References:

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Key_bindings
2. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html

Comment: This is asking about the readline settings for the Rails console, and does not mention zsh whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to point out that there is a gem called
rb-readline

this gem breaks rails console's ability to work in vi mode

(my project had bundled it because this gem was once necessary for byebug to work)